# How do I change this statically set range to a dynamic range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a summary sheet `Consolidated Tracker` and data sheets that won't be set statically as they'll be dates i.e `Sheet1 renamed May 2018` `Sheet2 renamed October 2018` `Sheet3 renamed May 2019` etc.

The follow code checks for a `match` in Column `B` across two statically set worksheets `Consolidated Tracker` and `May 2018`.

If a `match` is found, it takes the value from cell `C4` in `May 2018` and sets `C4` in the `Consolidated Tracker` to this value.

What I'd next like to achieve is to check:

- `Sheet3` and Set `D4` in the `Consolidated Tracker` if a match is found.
- `Sheet4` and set `E4` in the `Consolidated Tracker` if a match is found.
- `Sheet5` and set `F4` in the `Consolidated Tracker` if a match is found.

I've got this far by myself but I'm unsure how to procede from here.

Thank you.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateData()
    Dim WsDest As Worksheet 'destination workbook to write in
    Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")

    Dim WsSrc As Worksheet 'source workbook to match with
    Set WsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("May 2018")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'last used row in workbook
    LastRow = WsDest.Cells(WsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long, MatchedRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow 'loop through all rows from row 1 to last used row and update each row
        MatchedRow = 0 'initialize
        On Error Resume Next 'if no match found then ignore error
        MatchedRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(WsDest.Cells(iRow, "B"), WsSrc.Columns("B"), 0) 'get the row number of the match
        On Error GoTo 0 'reactivate error reporting

        If MatchedRow > 0 Then 'if a match was found then copy values
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, "C").Value = WsSrc.Cells(MatchedRow, "C").Value

        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't really understand what it is you're stuck on....

Comment: Are you wanting to change "May 2018" at some point? or rather, set "WsSrc" to be different sheets at various points?

Comment: Hi @Mistella sorry about that. Basically I'm only matching one column on one sheet. I want to match across multiple sheets and columns.

Comment: @Jamheadart essentially WsSrc is being set statically to May 2018. Instead I want this check to occur across all sheets. Copying and pasting the data when a match is found in sheet1. So in Sheet1(the summary), Sheet2 = B, Sheet3 = C, Sheet4 = D etc.

Comment: Maybe loop through sheets? Lots of threads on that topic.

Comment: Updated to make a little more sense I think.

Comment: @davesexcel I can loop through sheets happily enough but I'm not sure how to set the value into the correct cell (thank you for the question it's helping me figure what I need out).

Comment: Perhaps you could add a column counter which increments as you go through each sheet?. So it starts at 3 (C). Is that what you're missing?

Comment: @SJR I think so yes, when I get to the last row of data on sheet2, I want to move onto sheet3 and so on. I could I reference my names by index rather than name and say something like `loop` `worksheet+1`. I essentially want to check for data on every sheet, if there's a match, copy the data.

Comment: If the summary sheet is in the same workbook as the other sheets to loop through, you should add a check that the sheet you're currently searching for a match isn't the summary sheet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

It uses the sheet index but I'm uneasy about that because sheets can easily be re-ordered and your code will blow up.

As it stands the code will run through from the first to penultimate sheet (assuming your destination sheet is last) so you might need to adjust the `j` loop.

```
Public Sub UpdateData()

Dim WsDest As Worksheet 'destination workbook to write in
Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")

Dim LastRow As Long 'last used row in workbook
LastRow = WsDest.Cells(WsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long, MatchedRow As Variant, j As Long, c As Long

c = 3

For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow 'loop through all rows from row 1 to last used row and update each row
        MatchedRow = Application.Match(WsDest.Cells(iRow, "B"), Worksheets(j).Columns("B"), 0) 'get the row number of the match
        If IsNumeric(MatchedRow) Then 'if a match was found then copy values
            WsDest.Cells(iRow, c).Value = Worksheets(j).Cells(MatchedRow, "C").Value
        End If
    Next iRow
    c = c + 1
Next j

End Sub
```

Here is a better method which doesn't rely on sheet indexes.

```
Public Sub UpdateData()

Dim WsDest As Worksheet 'destination workbook to write in
Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")

Dim LastRow As Long 'last used row in workbook
LastRow = WsDest.Cells(WsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long, MatchedRow As Variant, c As Long, ws As Long

c = 3

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> WsDest.Name Then
        For iRow = 1 To LastRow 'loop through all rows from row 1 to last used row and update each row
            MatchedRow = Application.Match(WsDest.Cells(iRow, "B"), ws.Columns("B"), 0) 'get the row number of the match
            If IsNumeric(MatchedRow) Then 'if a match was found then copy values
                WsDest.Cells(iRow, c).Value = ws.Cells(MatchedRow, "C").Value
            End If
        Next iRow
        c = c + 1        
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: As always thank you @SJR it's working perfectly except it's only settings values starting at row D rather than row C.

Comment: Interestingly if I change `(MatchedRow, "C").Value` to `(MatchedRow, "B").Value` column C gets filled.

Comment: Thank you,, I've been racking my brains for two hours now. How do I swap this round if my destination sheet is my 1st sheet. I've been playing with c but none of the values I set `c` work.

Comment: `c` is the column number for the output, `j` is the worksheet counter, so try `For j = 2 To Sheets.Count`.

Comment: Variation to the code added above.

Comment: 'compile error: For Each control varibale must be a variant or object' @ 'For Each ws'

Comment: Set `ws as Worksheet` & it works same as before. It's still using D as the column output rather than C. I can just move the column headers over one that's fine but it's been annoying me I can't figure out why!

Comment: I made a small change to the second code block. I think it's just c was being incremented for the excluded sheet too.